I want to create a liquidity Pool on raydium, using CPI
I have my custom logic on a program and want to create a liquidity pool on Raydium using CPIs, I am aware of the Raydium SDK which interacts with the Raydium program, but I don't want to utilize it on the client side.
Another repo I found was this: raydium-contract-instructions. But not sure how to utilize it. Are there any docs or materials I can refer to, for this procedure?
Thanks in advance.
